# Is it a typo in an official document?

Tags: criminal-law

I am looking at a document about a criminal case, that is published [here](http://tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/mcfarlandgeorge.jpg). Knowing from the document it was created in 1992, I suppose the line saying 'Age at time of offense' is wrong saying 21, because DOB is 1960 and 'Date of offence' is 1991.

I wouldn't care much if it were not a local authority document, I'd just boldly assume it was a typo. But as it's issued by Texas Department of Criminal Justice, I am concerned about my understanding of English terms, though they seem to be quite obvious to be understood correctly.

Is a mistake like that likely to happen in serious cases like death penalty sentencing processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a report summary (addendum to a police report) or a corrections intake sheet; mistakes are common. I would be more shocked, but not completely surprised, it it were part of a published opinion. Clearly, they meant to say 31...you did not misinterpret it.